# Is the length of a Firebase Auth JWT Token always 1250 characters?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm including a `Firebase Auth Token` as part of my POST request to my REST api. I would want to check if the `token.length == 1250` before I decode the token to get the user's `uid`. I've generated ten different auth tokens and checked all of their length. All of them are 1250 characters in length. Are all of generated tokens' length in 1250 characters or will it sometimes be longer and shorter?

Comment: Sorry for not posting any code here because the problem is not about the code but about determining the length of firebase auth token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token lengths are arbitrary. It depends on the exact information included in the token such as user's name, uid and other custom claims.

Comment: what would be the max length though? I'm pretty sure there is a max length and min length for firebase's jwt token.

Comment: There are no bounds on the JWT length. There's a 1KB limit on the custom claims that can be included in the token. But since the token also encodes user and project specific information, it cannot have fixed bounds.